# creating userPattern for JNDIRealm

Tags: tomcat, jndi

Hey guys,
I have to meet a second distinguishion among users. I just pasted out the example given for [JNDIRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm)

dn: uid=jjones,ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com

```
<Realm   className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
    connectionName="cn=Manager,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
connectionPassword="secret"
     connectionURL="ldap://localhost:389"
      userPassword="userPassword"
       userPattern="uid={0},ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
          roleBase="ou=groups,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
          roleName="cn"
        roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
/>
```

***altered***

dn: uid=jjones,ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com

dn: uid=jjones,**ou=robots**,dc=mycompany,dc=com

```
<Realm   className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
    connectionName="cn=Manager,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
connectionPassword="secret"
     connectionURL="ldap://localhost:389"
      userPassword="userPassword"
       userPattern="uid={0},ou={0},dc=mycompany,dc=com"
          roleBase="ou=groups,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
          roleName="cn"
        roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
/>
```

Would this adjustment meet my requirement to enable a second distinguishion?
I don not know if "{0}" works or if I have to change it to "{1}".

And is it really true, that I don't need the "userBase" attribute, when I have a "userPattern" attribute defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is a userPatternArray

as follows:

> Sometimes it is necessary for users
>   from different organizational units to
>   have access to Code Collaborator. If
>   you are using direct-bind
>   configuration using the userPattern
>   attribute, you can change the
>   configuration to use userPatternArray
>   instead where the value is a
>   colon-separated list of user patterns.
>   For example, if there are users in
>   **ou=foo,dc=mycompany,dc=com and ou=bar,dc=mycompany,dc=com**
>   identified by their uid attribute, you
>   can set theuserPatternArray attribute
>   as follows:as follows:

```
userPatternArray="(uid={0},ou=foo,dc=mycompany,dc=com):(uid={0},ou=bar,dc=mycompany,dc=com)as follows:
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what I deduct from the manual and the above, I found in Tomcat 6.0.18 that it's the parameter userPattern, not userPatternArray that needs to be set with a colon-separated list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<Realm
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"  debug="99"
    connectionName="cn=administrator,ou=users,dc=Filenet,dc=com"
    connectionPassword="Password"
    connectionURL="ldap://localhost:389"
    userPattern="(cn={0},ou=sales,dc=Filenet,dc=com)(cn={0},ou=users,dc=Filenet,dc=com)"
    roleBase="ou=groups,dc=Filenet,dc=com"
    roleName="cn"
    roleSearch="(member={0})"/>
```